# Why If $f: A \rightarrow B$ is an $R$- module homomorphism then $f(T(A)) \subset T(B)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, torsion-groups

Why  If $f: A \rightarrow B$ is an $R$- module homomorphism then $f(T(A)) \subset T(B)$?, where $T(A)$ is called the torsion submodule.

Could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: Suppose that $r\in R$ is nonzero and $rm = 0$, i.e. $m$ is a torsion element in $A$. Then $f(rm) = r f(m)=0$. Since $r$ is nonzero, $f(m)$ is a torsion element of $B$.

Comment: The rest of the above statement in the book is "hence the restriction $f_{T}$ of $f$ to $T(A)$ is an $R$-module homomorphism $T(A) \rightarrow T(B).$" ...... I think this is trivially true because $T(A) \subset A$ and need not proof .... am I right or wrong? @PedroTamaroff